# Using a php named pipe

Tags: php, queue, named-pipes

**SITUATION:**

I have created a named pipe (in **php**) with the following code:

```
$pipeFile = "/files/queue";
posix_mkfifo($pipefile,0666);
```

and now I would like to be able to send and extract data to and from the pipe with **php** pages (like **readpipe.php**, and **put_in_pipe.php**).

---

**QUESTION:**

What function calls exist that I can use inside php files that can **send data** to the named pipe, and **receive data** from the named pipe?

Important: I already now how to send and receive data to and from the pipe via the terminal:

```
echo lol > /files/queue
cat /path/to/pipe
```

What I dont know is how to do this in a php script. If I have a page called **readpipe.php**, and someone enters it, the page would need to have a function call to get the next message inside the pipe (just like `cat ...` would do for the terminal), and similarly, a page called **put_in_pipe.php** would need code that puts a message into the pipe (just like `echo lol > ...`).

Any and all feedback is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of file IO functions available in PHP, e.g. `file_put_content`/`file_get_content` to write to the named pipe and read from it, but I doubt it is what you want. Pipes can hardly be used in the multi-page scenario you described.

Comment: There must be something out there though. I mean inter server-process communication is probably very common. I know I could make text files in folders, and have scripts checking if files exist and finding data inside, but that seems very inefficient. I thought maybe a queue system might be a great option, but all the queues I found online are coded with named pipes/sockets like pheanstalk. Would you recommend an alternative for inter server-process communication? I am at my last strings of hope at the moment.

Comment: That's a different yet much better question. Opinion based, unfortunately. Depending on what  kind of "inter-server" communication and level of persistence you need, it can be a database (sql, nosql, plain file etc) or a message broker (activemq, gearman, rabbitmq to name a few).

Comment: Alright so analysing those options for instance. Is beanstalkd/beanstalk/pheanstalk a message broker? Cause that was the queue system I originally was looking at, but that would fall into the "can hardly be used in a multi-page scenario you(meaning I) described" situation since it is in fact a queue that uses named pipes, and i believe rabbitmq is too (i could be wrong). ON the other hand, talking about databases, is it very common practice to use databases specifically for the purpose of sending data from 1 script to another? do you see any Pros or Cons in the matter?

Comment: I just made a new question with an extensive elaboration of what I have been researching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436692/database-for-inter-server-process-communication

Comment: Yes, beanstalk is a simplistic message broker. There are no pros and cons comparing to databases. They serve different purposes, and it is up to you to pick right tool to do the job. It wouldn't be fair to advise one, having 0 information about what you are trying to achieve. The fundamental difference between DB and MQ is the former is a storage with random access to data, and the later is a queue with sequential access to data. Regarding the linked question - it is a mess. Such architectural decisions require knowledge of a)business domain and b)available tools. You need to learn both.